# Angular - How to initialize auth interceptor before APP_INITIALIZER service is initialized?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application with an auth interceptor that adds a JWT to each request.

`auth.interceptor.ts` gets the user instance and JWT from the `user.service` as soon as it is available:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    currentUser: User;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.user$
            .subscribe(currentUser => this.currentUser = currentUser);
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser.token) {
            const requestWithAuthHeader = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.currentUser.token)
            });
            return next.handle(requestWithAuthHeader);

        }
    }
}
```

I have another service, that gets the `user` object from `user.service`, and sends an HTTP request as soon as `user` is available:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SettingsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.user$.pipe(
            filter(user => !!user && !!user.token), // wait until user is not null
        ).subscribe(() => this.fetchAppSettingsFromServer()); // sends an Http request
    }
}
```

`SettingsService` is loaded very early in the app, using the `APP_INITIALIZER` in the app.module:

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: () => () => null, deps: [SettingsService], multi: true },
```

This leads to a situaltion where `SettingsService` gets the `user` object early and sends an http request very quickly before the auth.interceptor has a chance to be initialized, and the result is an **http request without an added JWT**.

To solve this, I added a small `delay` in sending the request, to allow the auth.interceptor enough time to be initialized, and it works fine:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SettingsService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.user$.pipe(
            filter(user => !!user && !!user.token), // wait until user is not null
            delay(100) // wait until auth.interceptor is initialized
        ).subscribe(() => this.fetchAppSettings()); // must connect before app loads to support eaarly loading of data before component is diplayed
    }
    // ...
}
```

But this doesn't seem like the best solution, and there must be a more elegant way to do it. Any ideas how to make auth.interceptor get ready before `SettingsService` sends out a request?

Comment: You can try to add the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` injection token in your `deps` array. This way your app initializer should be executed with the interceptors ready to go.

Comment: Like so? `{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: () => () => null, deps: [HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, SettingsService], multi: true }` ? This didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking about, to put the interceptors as a dependency for your initializer function

Comment: instead of writing logic in the constructor could you please write it in a separate method and call it from AppComponent onInit.

Comment: @Octavian Mărculescu that didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @HPSingh - yes that would work, but that would break the reactive approach I'm trying to maintain in the app of executing code as soon as the data (user$) is ready, regardless of the components that use it.

Comment: Hey @RonEvans, Can u share your routing as well and any reason why using `APP_INITIALIZER` to load `SettingsService` ?

Comment: This was a product requirement that the settings must be available immediately when they are requested, so we couldn't allow fetching them only when the displaying component requested them as you would normally do (because it takes time to load them). Routing is quite complex and does affect this inter-service problem.

Comment: Your problem could be fix using `Resolvers`, that's y I am asking for routes, u can share high level routing at least

Comment: I added it to the question. We don't have resolvers defined on any route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, and it was in the way the auth-interceptor is configured to read the user object. Previously it was designed to "pull" the user object and save it to a local variable, like so:

```
this.userService.user$
     .subscribe(currentUser => this.currentUser = currentUser);
```

and then the intercept method used to check the locally saved User object:

```
if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser.token) { ... }
```

This approach of pulling a variable out of the observable and saving it to a local variable is an imperative approach and is discouraged when working with reactive RxJs observables, and in the example above it caused the `SettingsService`, triggered by the emitting of a new User, to run `this.fetchAppSettingsFromServer()` immediately before the auth-interceptor had a chance to pull the user object out of the `userService` and save it to a local object.

Changing this to a reactive approach solved the problem:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return this.userService.user$
            .pipe(
                first(), // in order to terminate the inner subscription after 1 emittion because I'm using 'pipe(finalize())' from the calling function.
 
                switchMap(currentUser => {
                    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
                        const requestWithAuthHeader = req.clone({
                            headers: req.headers.set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token)
                        });
                        return next.handle(requestWithAuthHeader);

                    } else {
                        console.log('User or token are not found, sending request without JWT to', req.url);
                        return next.handle(req);
                    }
                })
            );
    }
}
```

Now there's no need for the `pipe(delay(100))` before fetching app settings, and the settings can be fetched like so:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SettingsService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.user$.pipe(
            filter(user => !!user) // wait until user is initialized
            // delay(100) //this is no longer needed
        ).subscribe(() => this.configureAppSettings()); // must connect before app loads to support early loading of data before component is diplayed
    }
    /// ....
}
```